# What is the simplest way to use an external php library in a custom magento 2 module?

Tags: php, magento, block, external, magento2

I am new on magento I am currently working on a custom module for magento2 and I want to use an external php library (PHPMailer) within a Block file.

my project files structure:

ModuleFolder
---etc
.
.
---Block
------- Main.php
---lib
------- PHPMailer
.
.

I tried to include the PHPMailer class within my block main.php using:

```
require_once(__DIR__."/../lib/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php");
```

and for the class declaration i used :

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
```

also i tried to include the PHPMailer library in the Block folder and nothing works

it always returns :

```
PHPMailer class is not found in /...../Block/Main.php
```

And when i tried to put the PHPMailer.php directly in the Block folder like this:

---Block
-----Main.php
-----PHPMailer.php

and included

```
require_once(__DIR__."/PHPMailer.php");
```

it returns: cannot declare PHPMailer class in Main.php because the name is already in use in PHPMailer.php

I installed the latest version of PHPMailer from github: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

And i decided to use it because it is so easy and straightforward.

So how can i use this library and what is the best way for this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Using composer for PHPMailer and then use Magento 2's in-built dependency injection https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 2 is built with [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) as a first class citizen. You should use Composer to install PHPMailer as well: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#installation--loading

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

This means the PHPMailer class autoloading is taken care of by Composer, and you can use it immediately in your project code:

```
$mail = new \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
```

Comment: Thanks @Robbie I was really looking for a such simple answer.

Comment: Hello again :), I tried this solution on localhost and it works fine, but when i tried to run composer require phpmailer/phpmailer on the server i got the following error : 
cannot allocate memory 
I think that the error happens because i don't have enough memories on server.
So Is there an alternative way to use phpmailer without installing via composer ??

Comment: You shouldn't be using composer require/update on the server - you want to do all of that locally, commit your `composer.lock` file into your VCS repository and when you deploy to your server you just run `composer install` which will read from the lock file and download the dependencies

Comment: Magento 2 has a lot of dependencies, if you run out of memory on the CLI you could always try increasing it e.g. `php -d memory_limit=1G composer ...`