# How to install external libraries to magento2 without using composer?

Tags: php, magento, composer-php, phpmailer, magento2

I want to add phpmailer library to magento 2 so for that i followed the following answer [What is the simplest way to use an external php library in a custom magento 2 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607630/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-use-an-external-php-library-in-a-custom-magento-2-mo) and everything works fine on localhost. 
But when i tried to run

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

on server i got the following error

```
Fatal error : out of memory
```

I think that this happens because i don't have enough memories on my server.

So is there an alternative way to add the phpmailer library to magento2 without using composer ?

Comment: You have more likely not enough memory allocated to PHP - you should consider changing your php.ini for your php cli.

Comment: If you don't want to muck about with your memory, you just download php mailer into any directory and require it as needed. Composer just sorts everything out with a handy file. However, Magento is rather "heavy" so upping the memory would be worthwhile regardless. You could also composer install it on local and then FTP it up.

Comment: the max  php memory size that i can give is 768MB and this is not enough for running composer. So i tried to do what composer do manually by adding phpmailer library to vendor file and add phpmailer requirements in composer.json and composer.lock but still not working !
How can i put phpmailer in vendor manually and use it in my custom module ??
Thankss for help 
@Joshua

Comment: ^^ @DominicWehrmann

Comment: By default php-cli does not have a memory limit in php.ini. Merely installing PHPMailer is not a memory-intensive task, so there's something else going wrong here. Bundling static dependencies is generally a bad idea, especially if you're building a module that anyone else might use, because it means you're prone to leaving security holes unpatched. The PHPMailer readme file tells you how you can install it manually, but I'd really recommend figuring out what's wrong with your composer so you can do it the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I found a solution for this problem :
1- add the phpmailer library folder in a directory whithin the custom module folder
2- add the following in the block file

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

and use $mail = new PHPMailer();

for more info https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#installation--loading

Answer (score -1):

You can set memory_limit to carry out composer with the help of the following command:

```
php -d memory_limit=1000M /usr/local/bin/composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```